# AngularJS: How can I preserve a resource after calling save() on it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following example code using AngularJS:

```
$scope.thingy = new ThingyResource(); //Defined as an AngularJS resource already

$scope.thingy.bar = 'foo';

$scope.thingy.$save(
  {},
  // success handler
  function(data) {
    console.log($scope.thingy.bar);
  },
  // error handler
  function() {}
);
```

I would like to know how to preserve the values inside the success callback, as it just gives a base angularjs resource object with no sign of the 'bar' value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thingy.$save() will overwrite the values of thingy if the request is successfull. If you don't want that you can do ThingyResource.save() instead:

```
ThingyResource.save({},$scope.thingy,function(data){//success etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this broke in an update, but this does not work. My $scope.thingy is still getting overwritten with what ever is returned by the .save().

Comment: Great answer. But The first argument `{}` shouldn't be there. The correct is `ThingyResource.save($scope.thingy, function(data){...})`